# What are good defensive weapons in elite dangerous?

Tags: elite-dangerous

I am getting annoyed with the fact that I have to rely on my speed and FSD to get out of being attacked while mining/after being interdicted, and would like to know what the best defensive weapon is. What I am looking for is something that will get me out of a sticky situation relatively easily, but for a not-too-expensive price, as I am an amateur miner, and tend to earn money from completing transport missions, so money isn't the best for me. My ship is the viper MKIV, and my current weapons are 2 pulse lasers (gimballed) and a point defence. What I would really like is just something that could fire and/or aim automatically, and cause a decent amount of damage.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: This is my 100% defense strategy as a weaponless miner: I roll in a type-7 with no shields, and the best hull / thrusters / FSD I can find. I run from everyone, all the time, and I rely on chaff, point defense, and a heat sink launcher to get me out of there in one piece. The chaff seems to be what I need most often, pirates always have lasers, but the point defense is a lifesaver when missiles come into play. The heatsink launcher lets me boost to my heart's content without taking heat damage, and I'm usually gone before I fire my second chaff burst, with little or no hull damage.

Comment: I will leave it to someone else to research the most efficient use of power, credits, etc when buying a defensive weapon / system though. Efficiency can be limited by ship type, hardpoints, utility mounts, power supply, etc so the answer is hard to pin down.

Comment: ok, ill try adding more defensive items then, thanks

Comment: I don't do mining myself but as a trader I mostly rely on the speed to get out of dangerous situations as most of the time the ships that are attacking me are much bigger and well armed. Although I have some weapons on my cobra, in case i come across eagles or sidewinders. For most power efficient weapons I can recommend pulse lasers and multi-cannons. If you want to make sure that the weapon auto aim take turreted pulse laser but keep in mind that they do less DPM then gimbaled or fixed ones, but they are able to shoot even if you can't see an enemy (e.g when you try to run).

Comment: and as @Dpeif said get chaff launcher and some point defense, they can help you out in some tough situations.

Comment: @Pawel ok, thanks, I'll make sure to get a chaff launcher and some gimbaled weapons then.

Comment: Also you can check your build using these sites: http://www.edshipyard.com/  or http://www.coriolis.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lasers are good against shielded enemies but a multicannon will do far better against hull. I would go with one gimballed pulse laser and a gimballed multicannon, just fire both constantly. You're only going to be fighting if someone attacks you first, so you shouldn't need to worry about running out of ammo too much.

Chaff is also very good as it will make gimballed weapons miss when targeting you, which keeps you alive longer.

Comment: Is fighting back as a miner actually a sound strategy?

Comment: @Ellesedil it depends on the circumstances. If you're ambushed by an equal/weaker ship in a non-hazres, it may be worth fighting it until the security service arrives - it's extra cash (bounty voucher) and means you can continue mining right away. In a viper it may not be a good idea, but you may as well carry weapons just in case.

Comment: Doesn't adding weapons slow you down though? So it's possible that carrying them "just in case" is a disadvantage if you are running away most of the time.

Comment: @JonathanHartley It does slow you down, technically, but not by much. Size 1 weapons typically weigh 2T - you can see how they affect your speed by stashing them in outfitting while watching your maximum speed number.